# First time i imported fonts in pubspec.yaml file and it worked well and after 2 days there is error in the same code in font family

Tags: flutter, error-handling, runtime-error, font-family

[this is my pubspec.yaml file . on left you can see the font file. On first try it works normally now the same code gives an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGL0H.png)

[This is the main file where I used the font Font-family](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjkRd.png)

[this is my error message and my app doesn't open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzWFB.png)

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if indentation is correct in pubspec.yaml
2. run `flutter clean` in terminal and then rebuild the project